# Custom Material-UI button using an SVG?

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui

I'm trying to build a material-ui button which has a custom svg file as the button base as shown:

[image]

There will be a 'label' that should also be included in the button such as "submit" or "OK" or "Cancel".
is there some way i can use the material-ui button api / buttonbase api and implement this custom button so that all the rest of the material-ui button features are also available (like ripple effect etc.).

Comment: would [this](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#complex-buttons) helps you?

Comment: hi @hgb123, i've already gone through that material-ui example, but that doesn't provide any clarity on using SVG and inserting a button label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SvgIcon` component inside the `ButtonBase` component like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button
  },
}));

const CustomSvgButton = props => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" /> // replace with your path(s)
      <text
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
        dominantBaseline="middle"
        textAnchor="middle"
        fill="white">
        {props.label}
      </text>
    </SvgIcon>
  );
};

// ...
const classes = useStyles();

<ButtonBase focusRipple className={classes.root}>
  <CustomSvgButton
    label="Submit"
    color="primary"
    style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}
    viewBox="0 0 200 100"
  />
</ButtonBase>
```

I've used a `rect` for demonstration purposes, but you can replace this with your svg's path(s).

The styles at the top are optional, but this way the text looks like the `Typography` component.

**Update**

You can also import the svg as a component and pass it to the `component` prop on `SvgIcon` and put the text in the middle with `flexbox` like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as YourSvgButton } from "./yoursvgpath.svg";

// ...

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  label: {
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'white',
  },
}));

// ...

const CustomSvgButton = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <SvgIcon
        component={YourSvgButton}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}
        viewBox="0 0 200 100"
      />
      <Typography className={classes.label}>{props.label}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
};

// ...

<ButtonBase focusRipple>
  <CustomSvgButton label="Submit" />
</ButtonBase>
```

---

*Note that importing the svg as a component this way only works if you're using create-react-app as create-react-app uses SVGR (https://github.com/gregberge/svgr) under the hood. So if you're not using create-react-app you can use webpack and SVGR like described in the documentation to convert your svg to a react component: https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#component-prop.*

Comment: this seems like a good approach but my svg file is quite complex which has multiple <g> tags and multple <path> tags inside them. Is there some way I can import the svg as 'ReactComponent' or path string,  and then put a <text> tag into it?

Comment: Yes it is possible to import your svg as 'ReactComponent' and pass it to `SvgIcon`. I've updated my answer to show an example.